# Find overlapping matches between patterns in string with Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a string:

```
@~@item1@~@blablablablablabla;@~@item2@blablablablablablabla;@~@item3@~@blabla#####
```

I would like to capture using Regex whatever inside the @~@ @~@

```
$test = @~@item1@~@blablablablablabla;@~@item2@blablablablablablabla;@~@item3@~@blabla#####
$test -match '@~@\w*@~@'
$matches
```

then I would get only item1, how can I make sure I get all of them?

Comment: split on the `;`, filter out the strings that do NOT have the delimiter, split on the delimiter, take the 2nd item. that will give you `item` and `item3`, but not `item2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this scenario you are dealing with overlapping matches, so you'll want to have a regex like:

```
(?=@~@(.+?)@~@)
```

You can check out how the pattern works [here](https://regex101.com/r/8ocFhd/1).

---

You can use this pattern in Powershell as follows:

```
[regex]::matches($test,'(?=@~@(.+?)@~@)').Groups | Where-Object { $_.Value -ne $null} | Select-Object Value

Value                       
-----                       
                            
item1                       
                            
blablablablablabla;         
                            
item2@blablablablablablabla;
                            
item3
```

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to use two specific group constructs:

- Positive Lookbehind "(?<=...)", which is matching terms
  left to the/some target, but does not include it in results (acting like a filter)
- Positive Lookahead "(?=...)", which is matching terms right of the/some
  target, but does not include it in results (acting like a filter)

Test the following regex pattern:

```
    $regexPattern = '(?<=@~@)(.+?)(?=@~@|$)'
    
    $testString = '@~@item1@~@blablablablablabla;@~@item2@blablablablablablabla;@~@item3@~@blabla#####'
    $regexResult = [regex]::matches($testString,$regexPattern)
    
    $regexResult.Value
```

1. **(?<=@~@)**  --> Positive Lookbehind --> String match "@~@"
2. **(?=@~@|$)** --> Positive Lookahead --> String match "@~@" OR {END OF
   LINE ($)}

**Result:**

```
blablablablablabla;
item2@blablablablablablabla;
item3
blabla#####
```

P.S. and sorry:
The answer of @Paolo of course will work, except it does not handle terms at the end of line.
Just want to make it more clear using both positive lookup algorithm of regex.